# How forcibly to pass a type to templated constructor?

Tags: c++, templates

(tested on msvc2019)

We have such a class

```
struct AAA
{
    template<typename T>
    AAA(T val)
    {

    }
};

auto h = new AAA(5); // this way works (automatic type deduction)

//auto h2 = new AAA<int>(5); //compile errors. WHY? How to do it right?
//C2512 'AAA': no appropriate default constructor available
//C2062 type 'int' unexpected
```

So, how forcibly to pass a type to templated constructor (creating h2)?

Comment: It is impossible, see linked duplicate. Maybe explain why you need this, so that you can get an answer for a work-around instead.

Comment: `auto h = new AAA(int{5.});` gets the job done in most cases.

Comment: @super `int{5.}` won't compile.

Comment: old compiler (standard)? Try int(5)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Right, narrowing conversion. The idea is valid though.